# I am new to angular and i wanted to design (https://bl.ocks.org/ngminhtrung/ef06acdaa036365dd15746effce7f474) collapsible d3 force graph in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular13, d3-force-directed, force-directed-graph

I want to design this in Angular: https://bl.ocks.org/ngminhtrung/ef06acdaa036365dd15746effce7f474

In angular `d3.layout.force()` is not working and `d3.event` is throwing an error.

```js
d3.tree().links(nodes);
```

Gives:

`Property 'links' does not exist on type 'Simulation<SimulationNodeDatum, undefined>'.`

```js
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);
```

Gives:

```
export 'layout' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 
'd3' (possible exports: Adder, Delaunay, FormatSpecifier, InternMap, InternSet, Node, Voronoi, ZoomTransform, active, arc, area, areaRadial, ascending, autoType, axisBottom, axisLeft, axisRight, axisTop, bin, bisect, bisectCenter, bisectLeft, bisectRight, bisector, blob, blur, blur2, blurImage, brush, brushSelection, brushX, brushY, buffer, chord, chordDirected, chordTranspose, 
cluster, color, contourDensity, contours, count, create, creator, cross, csv, csvFormat, csvFormatBody, csvFormatRow, csvFormatRows, csvFormatValue, csvParse, csvParseRows, cubehelix, cumsum, curveBasis, curveBasisClosed, curveBasisOpen, curveBumpX, curveBumpY, curveBundle, curveCardinal, curveCardinalClosed, curveCardinalOpen, curveCatmullRom, curveCatmullRomClosed, curveCatmullRomOpen, curveLinear, curveLinearClosed, curveMonotoneX, curveMonotoneY, curveNatural, curveStep, curveStepAfter, curveStepBefore, descending, deviation, difference, disjoint, dispatch, drag, dragDisable, dragEnable, dsv, dsvFormat, easeBack, easeBackIn, easeBackInOut, easeBackOut, easeBounce, easeBounceIn, easeBounceInOut, easeBounceOut, easeCircle, easeCircleIn, easeCircleInOut, easeCircleOut, easeCubic, easeCubicIn, easeCubicInOut, easeCubicOut, easeElastic, easeElasticIn, easeElasticInOut, easeElasticOut, easeExp, easeExpIn, easeExpInOut, easeExpOut, easeLinear, easePoly, easePolyIn, easePolyInOut, easePolyOut, easeQuad, easeQuadIn, easeQuadInOut, easeQuadOut, easeSin, easeSinIn, easeSinInOut, easeSinOut, every, extent, fcumsum, filter, flatGroup, flatRollup, forceCenter, forceCollide, forceLink, forceManyBody, forceRadial, forceSimulation, forceX, forceY, format, formatDefaultLocale, formatLocale, formatPrefix, formatSpecifier, fsum, geoAlbers, geoAlbersUsa, geoArea, geoAzimuthalEqualArea, geoAzimuthalEqualAreaRaw, geoAzimuthalEquidistant, geoAzimuthalEquidistantRaw, geoBounds, geoCentroid, geoCircle, geoClipAntimeridian, geoClipCircle, geoClipExtent, geoClipRectangle, geoConicConformal, geoConicConformalRaw, geoConicEqualArea, geoConicEqualAreaRaw, geoConicEquidistant, geoConicEquidistantRaw, geoContains, geoDistance, geoEqualEarth, geoEqualEarthRaw, geoEquirectangular, geoEquirectangularRaw, geoGnomonic, geoGnomonicRaw, geoGraticule, geoGraticule10, geoIdentity, geoInterpolate, geoLength, geoMercator, geoMercatorRaw, geoNaturalEarth1, geoNaturalEarth1Raw, geoOrthographic, geoOrthographicRaw, geoPath, geoProjection, 
geoProjectionMutator, geoRotation, geoStereographic, geoStereographicRaw, geoStream, geoTransform, geoTransverseMercator, geoTransverseMercatorRaw, gray, greatest, greatestIndex, group, groupSort, groups, hcl, hierarchy, histogram, hsl, html, image, index, indexes, interpolate, interpolateArray, interpolateBasis, interpolateBasisClosed, interpolateBlues, interpolateBrBG, interpolateBuGn, interpolateBuPu, interpolateCividis, interpolateCool, interpolateCubehelix, interpolateCubehelixDefault, interpolateCubehelixLong, interpolateDate, interpolateDiscrete, interpolateGnBu, interpolateGreens, interpolateGreys, interpolateHcl, interpolateHclLong, interpolateHsl, interpolateHslLong, interpolateHue, interpolateInferno, interpolateLab, interpolateMagma, interpolateNumber, interpolateNumberArray, interpolateObject, interpolateOrRd, interpolateOranges, interpolatePRGn, interpolatePiYG, 
interpolatePlasma, interpolatePuBu, interpolatePuBuGn, interpolatePuOr, interpolatePuRd, interpolatePurples, interpolateRainbow, interpolateRdBu, interpolateRdGy, interpolateRdPu, interpolateRdYlBu, interpolateRdYlGn, interpolateReds, interpolateRgb, interpolateRgbBasis, interpolateRgbBasisClosed, interpolateRound, interpolateSinebow, interpolateSpectral, interpolateString, interpolateTransformCss, interpolateTransformSvg, interpolateTurbo, interpolateViridis, interpolateWarm, interpolateYlGn, interpolateYlGnBu, interpolateYlOrBr, interpolateYlOrRd, interpolateZoom, interrupt, intersection, interval, isoFormat, isoParse, json, 
lab, lch, least, leastIndex, line, lineRadial, link, linkHorizontal, linkRadial, linkVertical, local, map, matcher, max, maxIndex, mean, median, medianIndex, merge, min, minIndex, mode, namespace, namespaces, nice, now, pack, packEnclose, packSiblings, pairs, partition, path, permute, pie, piecewise, pointRadial, pointer, pointers, polygonArea, polygonCentroid, polygonContains, 
polygonHull, polygonLength, precisionFixed, precisionPrefix, precisionRound, quadtree, quantile, quantileIndex, quantileSorted, quantize, quickselect, radialArea, radialLine, randomBates, randomBernoulli, randomBeta, randomBinomial, randomCauchy, randomExponential, randomGamma, randomGeometric, randomInt, randomIrwinHall, randomLcg, randomLogNormal, randomLogistic, randomNormal, randomPareto, randomPoisson, randomUniform, randomWeibull, range, rank, reduce, reverse, rgb, ribbon, ribbonArrow, rollup, rollups, scaleBand, scaleDiverging, scaleDivergingLog, scaleDivergingPow, scaleDivergingSqrt, scaleDivergingSymlog, scaleIdentity, scaleImplicit, scaleLinear, scaleLog, scaleOrdinal, scalePoint, scalePow, scaleQuantile, scaleQuantize, scaleRadial, scaleSequential, scaleSequentialLog, scaleSequentialPow, scaleSequentialQuantile, scaleSequentialSqrt, scaleSequentialSymlog, scaleSqrt, scaleSymlog, scaleThreshold, scaleTime, scaleUtc, scan, schemeAccent, schemeBlues, schemeBrBG, schemeBuGn, schemeBuPu, schemeCategory10, schemeDark2, schemeGnBu, schemeGreens, schemeGreys, schemeOrRd, schemeOranges, schemePRGn, schemePaired, schemePastel1, schemePastel2, schemePiYG, schemePuBu, schemePuBuGn, schemePuOr, schemePuRd, schemePurples, schemeRdBu, schemeRdGy, schemeRdPu, schemeRdYlBu, schemeRdYlGn, schemeReds, schemeSet1, schemeSet2, schemeSet3, schemeSpectral, schemeTableau10, schemeYlGn, schemeYlGnBu, schemeYlOrBr, schemeYlOrRd, select, selectAll, selection, selector, selectorAll, shuffle, shuffler, some, sort, stack, stackOffsetDiverging, stackOffsetExpand, stackOffsetNone, stackOffsetSilhouette, stackOffsetWiggle, stackOrderAppearance, 
stackOrderAscending, stackOrderDescending, stackOrderInsideOut, stackOrderNone, stackOrderReverse, stratify, style, subset, sum, superset, svg, symbol, symbolAsterisk, symbolCircle, symbolCross, symbolDiamond, symbolDiamond2, symbolPlus, symbolSquare, symbolSquare2, symbolStar, symbolTriangle, symbolTriangle2, symbolWye, symbolX, symbols, symbolsFill, symbolsStroke, text, thresholdFreedmanDiaconis, thresholdScott, thresholdSturges, tickFormat, tickIncrement, tickStep, ticks, timeDay, timeDays, timeFormat, timeFormatDefaultLocale, timeFormatLocale, timeFriday, timeFridays, timeHour, timeHours, timeInterval, timeMillisecond, timeMilliseconds, timeMinute, timeMinutes, timeMonday, timeMondays, timeMonth, timeMonths, timeParse, timeSaturday, timeSaturdays, 
timeSecond, timeSeconds, timeSunday, timeSundays, timeThursday, timeThursdays, timeTickInterval, timeTicks, timeTuesday, timeTuesdays, timeWednesday, timeWednesdays, timeWeek, timeWeeks, timeYear, timeYears, timeout, timer, timerFlush, transition, transpose, tree, treemap, treemapBinary, treemapDice, treemapResquarify, treemapSlice, treemapSliceDice, treemapSquarify, tsv, tsvFormat, tsvFormatBody, tsvFormatRow, tsvFormatRows, tsvFormatValue, tsvParse, tsvParseRows, union, utcDay, utcDays, utcFormat, utcFriday, utcFridays, utcHour, utcHours, utcMillisecond, utcMilliseconds, utcMinute, utcMinutes, utcMonday, utcMondays, utcMonth, utcMonths, utcParse, utcSaturday, utcSaturdays, utcSecond, utcSeconds, utcSunday, utcSundays, utcThursday, utcThursdays, utcTickInterval, utcTicks, utcTuesday, utcTuesdays, utcWednesday, utcWednesdays, utcWeek, utcWeeks, utcYear, utcYears, variance, window, xml, zip, zoom, zoomIdentity, zoomTransform)

Error: src/app/dependency-graph/dependency-graph.component.ts:65:20 - error TS2339: Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'typeof import()'.
```

```js
var force = d3.layout.force()
                      ~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you importing d3 in your ts file? 

Try `import * as d3 from 'd3';`

d3 can be weird with imports and you are probably not importing correctly

Comment: import * as d3 from 'd3';
it is already added, still not able to use it, actually in angular d3.layout is not available and it gives error

Comment: These are my imports
`import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  ElementRef,
  ViewChild,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap, startWith, debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { ForceLink } from 'd3';`

Comment: try removing `.layout` from `var force = d3.layout.force()`.